# XML Path expression to include Special Characters

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I am trying this SQL to get the firstname and lastname from SQL Server 2008 tables using XML Path expression. The data contains special characters. When I try the sql, I get an error the following error:

> FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'LastName' because it contains a character (0x001B) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive

How can I rewrite the SQL to include these characters in the xml ( maybe as CDATA?)

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT  A1.FirstName
        ,   A1.LastName
    FROM    dbo.kc_consumer AS A1
    FOR  XML PATH('Consumer') , TYPE) 
     AS ConsumerData
FOR XML PATH('Element'), ROOT('Elements')
```

Comment: What's your @@VERSION say? I ask because when I try a FOR XML query against a constant string with that character specifically added, the escaping works perfectly fine. (Using SP1 - 10.50.2550.0) Also, that's 2008 R2

Comment: @Jaaz Cole  - My SQL Version is   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4286.0 (X64). I think there must be some special character in the names that makes it bad. I am trying to figure out what it is

Comment: Are you sure that you need to include these characters in your data? In my dataset, I noticed that these strange characters were for data that I didn't actually want to include (like spam or attempted malware injection, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pull the TYPE directive into the outer query. Using it bypasses the character escaping that SQL Server does in a normal FOR XML statement, but once your results are escaped (using FOR XML without TYPE), your results can be included in an XML TYPE directive statement. Edit: The original fiddle has died somehow. It's unstable. Instead, here's a block of code that works.

```
DECLARE @kc_consumer table (FirstName VARCHAR(20), LastName VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @kc_consumer VALUES
    ('John','Smith' + NCHAR(27))
  , ('Jane','123ú♂
2⌂¶2<PZdûá╚' + NCHAR(27))
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
              (SELECT A1.FirstName + '' FOR XML PATH('')) FirstName
            , (SELECT A1.LastName  + '' FOR XML PATH('')) LastName
        FROM @kc_consumer AS A1
        FOR XML PATH('Consumer'), TYPE
    )
FOR XML PATH('Element'), ROOT('Elements'), TYPE;
```

Comment: @jaaz-cole, that fiddle isn't working anymore. I'm trying to figure out if I can use your solution by wrapping an extra FOR XML PATH query around one of my queries that is having this problem.

Comment: This resolved the error but then it prints unwanted characteres like >> 'D&#x1E;eliberate' . I don't wanna use REPLACE here.

Answer (score 5):

I tested this with ASCII characters 0-255 and found out that you get this error for characters: `0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0x0004, 0x0005, 0x0006, 0x0007, 0x0008, 0x000B, 0x000C, 0x000E, 0x000F, 0x0010, 0x0011, 0x0012, 0x0013, 0x0014, 0x0015, 0x0016, 0x0017, 0x0018, 0x0019, 0x001A, 0x001B, 0x001C, 0x001D, 0x001E, 0x001F`.

One workaround is to remove `, TYPE` from your XML statement.

Another way is to remove those characters in the select statement:

```
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
    < YOUR EXPRESSION TO BE CLEANED >
,char(0x0000),'') ,char(0x0001),'') ,char(0x0002),'') ,char(0x0003),'') ,char(0x0004),'') 
,char(0x0005),'') ,char(0x0006),'') ,char(0x0007),'') ,char(0x0008),'') ,char(0x000B),'') 
,char(0x000C),'') ,char(0x000E),'') ,char(0x000F),'') ,char(0x0010),'') ,char(0x0011),'') 
,char(0x0012),'') ,char(0x0013),'') ,char(0x0014),'') ,char(0x0015),'') ,char(0x0016),'') 
,char(0x0017),'') ,char(0x0018),'') ,char(0x0019),'') ,char(0x001A),'') ,char(0x001B),'') 
,char(0x001C),'') ,char(0x001D),'') ,char(0x001E),'') ,char(0x001F),'')
```

You could also create a function with these replace statements.