# FOR XML could not serialize the data for node because it contains a character (0x000E)

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to use FOR XML in SSRS, but when the report runs it sometimes gives me this error:

```
FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'NoName' because it contains a character (0x000E) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive.
```

I'm using FOR XML to concatenate a comments column into one cell within SSRS. Since multiple comments can exist for one user, this would solve the issue with duplicates. Does anyone have an idea why I would get this error in SSRS?

Comment: I can tell you why you get the error, but the error message already tells you that (XML does not allow the character 0x000E). I'm afraid I can't tell you what to do about it without knowing much more about your project.

Comment: Do you know of a way I could query for the values that are causing the error?

Comment: Not knowing SSRS, no, sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Path expression to include Special Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147627/xml-path-expression-to-include-special-characters)

Answer (score 7):

It appears to be a special character that looks like a musical note.  You can find the row that is causing your problem like this:

```
SELECT Notes FROM MyTable WHERE Notes like '%' + char(0x000E) + '%'
```

You can fix the problem by removing the offending character.

```
 UPDATE MyTable SET Notes = REPLACE(Notes, char(0x000E) , '') 
 WHERE Notes like '%' + char(0x000E) + '%'
```

Comment: this method works great. Any idea if there's a way to search for an entire set of those types of special characters? I keep finding more in my data.